# Zero value printed due to logic error in int data assignment

Tags: java, int

This code produces accurate output, aside from the final column of data output.

The output is meant to show the non-decimal vote percent value of the candidates.

An error in my logic has caused the aforementioned value to print as 0.

Output appears as follows:

[image: CandidateTester output.]

```
public class Candidate {
    public String name;
    public int numVotes;

    public Candidate(String name, int numVotes) {
        this.name = name;
        this.numVotes = numVotes;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getNumVotes() {
        return numVotes;
    }

    public String toString() { 
        return getName() + " received " + getNumVotes() + " votes.";
    }
}


import java.util.*;
public class TestCandidate {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        ArrayList<Candidate> list = new ArrayList<Candidate>();
        list.add(new Candidate("John Smith", 5000));
        list.add(new Candidate("Mary Miller", 4000));
        list.add(new Candidate("Michael Duffy", 6000));
        list.add(new Candidate("Tim Robinson", 2500));
        list.add(new Candidate("Joe Ashtony", 1800));

        System.out.println("Results per candidate:");
        System.out.println("______________________\n");

        int total = getTotal(list);
        printVotes(list);
        System.out.print("\nCandidate\t\tVotes Received\t\t% of Total Votes");
        printResults(list);
        System.out.println("\n\nTotal number of votes in election: " + total);
    }

    public static void printResults(ArrayList<Candidate> list) {
        String name = "";
        int percent = 0;
        int votes = 0;
        int total = getTotal(list);
        for(Candidate token : list) {
           name = token.getName();
           votes = token.getNumVotes();
           percent = (votes / total) * 100;
           System.out.printf("\n%1s\t%12d\t%17d", name, votes, percent);
        }
    }

    public static void printVotes(ArrayList<Candidate> list) {
        for(Candidate token : list) {
            System.out.println(token);
        }
    }

    public static int getTotal(ArrayList<Candidate> list) {
        int total = 0;
        for(Candidate token : list) {
            total += token.getNumVotes();
        }
        return total;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are performing integer division here.

```
percent = (votes / total) * 100;
```

`votes` will always be inferior or egal than `total`, so it's likely that `votes/total` will result in 0 due to integer division.

Either change `percent` as `double` and cast one of the operand of the division to `double`, or if you want to keep `percent` as an integer, multiply `vote` by 100 first and then divide it by `total`.

```
percent = (votes*100) / total;
```

Comment: You know, I tried casting them a few times. It kept returning 0's. Obviously I mixed something up. Thanks. Stupid mistake.

Comment: @alx I don't know how you tried to cast it (`percent = (int)(((double)votes / total) * 100);` should work but not recommended, just multiply by 100 first in this case if you want to keep an integer)

Comment: votes * 1.0 / total * 100, since both votes and total are integers

Comment: @SaraSeppola Yes but you would need to make percent as double then and  `(double)votes / total * 100;` would be fine too.

Comment: @ZouZou that's similar to what I did (except I obviously misplaced something). Your fix is much more simple and elegant. Cheers.